# How do I left-align buttons in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

The following code

```py
root = tk.Tk()
frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frame.grid()

# Browse
tk.Text(frame, state="disabled", height=1).grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, sticky="W", pady=5, ipadx=2, ipady=2)
ttk.Button(frame, text="Browse", command=None).grid(column=3, row=0, sticky="E")

# Selected files
tk.Text(frame, state="disabled").grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=4, sticky="EW", pady=10)

# Options
ttk.Button(frame, text="SELECT", command=None).grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="W")
ttk.Button(frame, text="DELETE", command=None).grid(column=1, row=2, sticky="W")
ttk.Button(frame, text="Merge", command=None).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky="W")

ttk.Button(frame, text="Close", command=root.destroy).grid(column=3, row=2, sticky="E")

root.mainloop()
```

produces this,

[image: gui]

but I want the `DELETE` and `MERGE` buttons to be left-aligned so they are together with the `SELECT` button. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Put buttons in new Frame which you put in current frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put buttons in new Frame and this frame put in original Frame

```
buttons_frame = ttk.Frame(frame)
buttons_frame.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="W")

ttk.Button(buttons_frame, text="SELECT", command=None).grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="W")
ttk.Button(buttons_frame, text="DELETE", command=None).grid(column=1, row=2, sticky="W")
ttk.Button(buttons_frame, text="Merge", command=None).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky="W")
```

[image]

**BTW:**

In `buttons_frame` you may even use `.pack(side='left')` instead of `grid()`

---

Full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frame.grid()

# Browse
tk.Text(frame, state="disabled", height=1).grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, sticky="W", pady=5, ipadx=2, ipady=2)
ttk.Button(frame, text="Browse", command=None).grid(column=3, row=0, sticky="E")

# Selected files
tk.Text(frame, state="disabled").grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=4, sticky="EW", pady=10)

# Options
buttons_frame = ttk.Frame(frame)
buttons_frame.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="W")
ttk.Button(buttons_frame, text="SELECT", command=None).grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="W")
ttk.Button(buttons_frame, text="DELETE", command=None).grid(column=1, row=2, sticky="W")
ttk.Button(buttons_frame, text="Merge", command=None).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky="W")

ttk.Button(frame, text="Close", command=root.destroy).grid(column=3, row=2, sticky="E")

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

You may also add empy column between `Merge` and `Close` and  assign `weight=1` to this column so it will get all empty space.

It needs to move `Browse` and `Close` to next column, and increase `columnspan` in both `Text`

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frame.grid()

frame.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)  # column 3 will use all free space

# Browse
tk.Text(frame, state="disabled", height=1).grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=4, sticky="W", pady=5, ipadx=2, ipady=2)
ttk.Button(frame, text="Browse", command=None).grid(column=4, row=0, sticky="E")

# Selected files
tk.Text(frame, state="disabled").grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=5, sticky="EW", pady=10)

# Options
ttk.Button(frame, text="SELECT", command=None).grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="W")
ttk.Button(frame, text="DELETE", command=None).grid(column=1, row=2, sticky="W")
ttk.Button(frame, text="Merge", command=None).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky="W")

ttk.Button(frame, text="Close", command=root.destroy).grid(column=4, row=2, sticky="E")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I added example with free column and `columnconfigure(3, weight=1)`